# Display all labels in x-axis in HighCharts Stock

Tags: highcharts, axis-labels

I am using Stock High Charts, I want to display all the labels in x-axis (the labels show city names). How do I achieve this?

```
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                rotation: -50,
                step: 1                        
            }                   
        },
```

Comment: Do you have some live demo, like jsFiddle? I guess you need to set `labels.step = 1`, but Highstock doesn't support categorized axis, so it's hard to guess how did you achieved that.

Comment: Thanks Pawel for the response. Please check edited question.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't explain anything :) Post full Highcharts code with some data-sample or recreate issue on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the value of **height**. That's the solution I had to apply.

Example code:

```
chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 1000
    }
```